# How does project.getProperty() work in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy, metaclass, mop

Gradle API doesn't have this method, but there's no compile error, and it does get the property at runtime.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html

I tried using a debugger to discover what happened behind the scene, the call actually landed on `PogoGetPropertySite#getProperty`.

What really happened?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59000077/access-dot-property-stored-in-gradle-properties-within-settings-gradle/59035342#59035342