# Access dot property stored in gradle.properties within settings.gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a `Gradle 6.0.1` project. The `build.gradle` (excerpt) looks like:

```
plugins {
  id "application"
  id "com.github.edeandrea.xjc-generation"
  id "eclipse"
  id "idea"
  id "java"
  id "org.springframework.boot"
}

...

dependencies {
  implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${property("spring-boot.version")}")

  // ...more stuff here
}

// ...more stuff here
```

I'm managing all the plugin versions in `settings.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {
  plugins {
    id "application"
    id "com.github.edeandrea.xjc-generation" version "1.0"
    id "eclipse"
    id "idea"
    id "java"
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "${spring-boot.version}"
  }
}

rootProject.name = "spring-core"
```

...and I usually put the artifact versions in `gradle.properties`:

```
#
# Dependency Versions
oracle.version = 18.3.0.0
spring-boot.version = 2.2.1.RELEASE

#
# Gradle Settings
org.gradle.configureondemand = false
org.gradle.daemon = false

#
# System Settings
systemProp.file.encoding = UTF-8
systemProp.sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
```

Now the problem is I can't read dot-properties in `settings.gradle` (from `gradle.properties`) in the same way I do it inside `build.gradle` — I already tried using `${property("spring-boot.version")}`.

Is there any way to achieve that? I can easily change the key to something like `springBootVersion` and it works, but I wonder if there is a way to have in the way I currently have it: `spring-boot.version`.

Comment: getProperty("spring-boot.version")

Comment: Ugh! That worked :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `getProperty("spring-boot.version")`

---

simple gradle project with additional variants

```groovy
task test{
    doLast {
        //success
        println project.property('aaa.bbb.ccc')
        println project.'aaa.bbb.ccc'
        println getProperty('aaa.bbb.ccc')

        //failure: Could not get unknown property 'aaa.bbb.ccc' for task ':test' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
        println property('aaa.bbb.ccc') 
    }
}
```

gradle.properties

```
aaa.bbb.ccc=12345
```

---

`property('aaa.bbb.ccc')` fails because it tries to get property on current object (task) but `aaa.bbb.ccc` defined for project

however `project.property('aaa.bbb.ccc')` succeeds because it should

`project.'aaa.bbb.ccc'` is the same as `project.getProperty('aaa.bbb.ccc')` in groovy

`project.getProperty('aaa.bbb.ccc')` works because of groovy basic object [`GroovyObject`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyObject.html) (IHMO)

and `getProperty(name)` without prefix actualy located in [org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/groovy/scripts/BasicScript.java#L64) and not really documented...

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The question was how to access the properties from within the SETTINGS.gradle, not the BUILD.gradle.

Comment: @ChristianCiach actually this the answer IMHO. This question is about accessing some project-level properties, typically defined in `settings.gradle`, whose naming, with an embedded dot, makes them tricky to reference in the groovy GStrings found in`build.gradle`

Answer (score 5):

For me the solution from @daggett doesn't work. But I was able to access a property defined inside the `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` from the `settings.gradle` this way:

```
settings.ext.find('MY_PROPERTY')
```

To provide some context, I'm using this to read the credentials for the Gradle Build Cache Node remote server:

```
buildCache {
    boolean isCiServer = System.getenv().containsKey("CI")
    remote(HttpBuildCache) {
        enabled = settings.ext.find('GRADLE_BUILD_CACHE_NODE_PWD') != null
        url = 'https://myserver:443/cache/'
        allowUntrustedServer = true
        push = isCiServer
        credentials {
            username = settings.ext.find('GRADLE_BUILD_CACHE_NODE_USR')
            password = settings.ext.find('GRADLE_BUILD_CACHE_NODE_PWD')
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Another solution that does not require the use of `ext`:

```
username = settings.hasProperty('GRADLE_BUILD_CACHE_NODE_USR') ? settings.GRADLE_BUILD_CACHE_NODE_USR : null
```

Comment: `settings.extra.properties["my.property"]` worked for me in the Kotlin DSL and Gradle 8